# Insert Calendar API google via components REST Delphi resposta 401

Tags: delphi, google-calendar

Estou tentando utilizar os componentes REST para fazer uma requisição HTTP com o método **POST** para inserir um calendário na API, mas a minha requisição está retornando o erro "401 - Não autorizado".

Estou tentando incluir o `token` na requisição, mas não sei se estou fazendo de maneira correta. Como posso corrigir isso?

Meu código atual

```
procedure TOAuth2TesterFrm.incluir_btnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
json,outro_json,token: String;
begin
token:=AccessTokenEdt.Text;
json:=(
'{"kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry", "etag": "0", "id": "iago21092020@gmail.com", ' +
'"summary": "Calendario Outro", "description": "Descrição do evento", '   +
'{"date": "2020 August 11", "dateTime": "2020-08-11T17:35:36+03:00"}'+
'"timeZone": "Brasília-DF", "colorId": "15", "backgroundColor": "#9fc6e7", "foregroundColor": "#000000", ' +
'"selected": true, "accessRole": "owner", "primary": true, '+
 '"defaultReminders": [{"method": "popup", "minutes": 30}, {"method": "email", "minutes": 10}], '  +
'"notificationSettings": {"notifications": [{"method": "email", "type": "eventCreation"}, ' +
'{"method": "email", "type": "eventChange"}, {"method": "email", "type": "eventCancellation"}, ' +
'{"method": "email", "type": "eventResponse"}]}}');
outro_json:='{"summary": "Batata"}';
try
    client.ResetToDefaults;
    request.ResetToDefaults;
    response.ResetToDefaults;

    client.BaseURL:='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/';
    response.ContentType := 'application/json';
    request.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
    request.Body.ClearBody;
    request.AddBody(outro_json);
    client.AcceptEncoding:='utf-8';
    client.ContentType:='application/json';
    request.Resource := 'calendars';
    request.Params.AddHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+token);
    request.Params.ParameterByName('Authorization').Options := [poDoNotEncode];


    request.Execute;
    ShowMessage(request.Response.StatusCode.ToString);
finally
  request.Free;
      response.Free;
      client.Free;

end;
  end;
```

Comment: O header `Authorization` está sendo enviado e rejeitado (token inválido) ou não está sendo enviado?

Comment: Eu acredito que ele não está sendo enviado, porque é um token válido. É que nessa procedure só tem o Insert, mas na outra parte do app eu faço o login com o google e resgato o  token

Comment: Você testou esse token enviando uma requisição pelo Postman ou Insomnia (por exemplo) para ter certeza de que pegou o token correto? Eu não sei Delphi, mas esse detalhe é importante

Comment: Vou tentar usar o Postman, mas eu acredito que seja o token certo

Comment: Você estava certo, pelo Insomnia também deu 401... Então o token é inválido...
E agora, preciso de um token válido :(

Comment: Mesmo eu gerando vários tokens diferentes e tentando o envio, a request me retorna 401. Ela pode retornar isso por algum outro motivo, além de token inválido??

Comment: Marca como resolvido.